# Dask meta for map_partitions dataframe

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

I am trying to to use `map_partitions` with a custom function in Dask which I want to return a dataframe with a couple columns, but when I supply the metadata I receive the following error:

`Exception: AttributeError("'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'")`

If I specify `meta` as a series it works fine, but if I pass meta an empty dataframe I receive the above.

```py
def mytest(self, df):
        return df['Bedrooms']

meta = ('Bedrooms', 'i8') #This works
meta = pd.DataFrame({'Bedrooms': pd.Series(dtype='i8')}) #This doesn't

bedrooms = df.map_partitions(self.mytest, weather_file_location, year, meta=meta)
```

The series solution was just for testing as I really need to work with a dataframe with multiple columns. I am not sure if I am just not creating the empty dataframe correctly or if there is another way to pass meta for a dataframe?

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) and then try to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing some additional testing the problem seems to be passing a single column does not work, but multiple columns does.

```
meta = pd.DataFrame({'Bedrooms': pd.Series(dtype='i8', 'Lights': pd.Series(dtype='i8')})
```

Comment: I believe that a single column will come back as a Series, not a DataFrame.

Comment: Thanks! Yes that seems to be the case.